# Unity game compiled in Windows doesn’t open in Mac

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

I created an Unity game in Windows and I wanted to pass it to a Mac computer. I built it for Mac and I uploaded the .app folder to Google Drive as a .rar. Then, I downloaded it in a Mac and I unzipped it. When I try to open it, it shows the error message “Someapp.app can’t be opened”. It doesn’t explain why. I think the problem isn’t from Unity because the log file is empty after the error. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed to make the actual executable in the .app folder, well, “executable”.
Please try:

Open up a Terminal and navigate to your app folder:

`cd <PATH_TO_YOUR_APP>/<APP_NAME>.app/Contents/MacOS/`

This folder contains the actual executable file which Windows apparently didn’t make executable. Let’s add the executable flag:

`chmod +x <APP_NAME>`

Afterwards I could start the app.

Answer (score 1):

I made the Build for my project for both PC and Mac, however I had massive issues getting the Mac one to actually work. Here is the tutorial I used to make the builds which was suppppper helpful, but it didn't help fix my issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=3&v=7nxKAtxGSn8&feature=emb_title

I just figured out how to make the Mac build work with a friend and it was a bit of work. Once you follow the video's directions exactly for the Mac version, you can send the file to your Mac but when you do it will be labeled MacOS and then when you try to open it it will most likely fail and say missing application to open.

From what I have learned, this is because the compression actually corrupts the executable file to open it on the Mac. To fix this, you have to use Terminal to navigate your way into the file and unlock the permission settings that were changed due what we believe is from the compression.

I honestly can't remember where I found this code but the navigation part I got from the other answer here, but you need to open up a Terminal and navigate to your app folder:

cd <PATH_TO_YOUR_APP>/<APP_NAME>.app/Contents/MacOS/

and add the following:

chmod -R 777 [applicationName].app

This unlocked the permissions on the application but when the app was opened, we had to allow permission through the Mac firewall to let it run on the computer. Once we approved permission, the app ran no problem.

I hope this helps and I'm by no means a professional with this so but my friend and I can try to help in anyway possible.